# If any element in setA is in setB

Tags: objective-c, nsset, nsmutableset

Just a quick question regarding sets in Obj-c. Given two sets:

```
NSMutableSet* a = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects: 1, 2, 3, nil];
NSMutableSet* b = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects: 3, 4, 5, nil];
```

is there a quick and easy way to determine if any element in set A is also in set B?

Something like ...

```
if ([a contains:[b allObjects]])
   // do something
```

Comment: In other words, is the intersection non-empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`-intersectsSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000143-CHDCFHHG) is for.

```
if ([a intersectsSet:b])
    // do something
```

Comment: Okay. So later in my program when I want to remove all elements of one set from another, what should I do?

Comment: @Clever: Create an `NSMutableSet` containing your "master" set, and call `-minusSet:`, passing in the set you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. One more quick one--- what kind of efficiency gain am I looking at from using a set compared to an NSMutableArray? It shouldn't really matter, I wouldn't think, until I'm into a very high amount of objects?

Comment: @Clever: Depends on what you're doing. A set is an unordered collection that has amortized constant-time access/mutation, just like a dictionary (because they're both backed by a hash table). An array is an ordered collection that has constant-time access to an individual element, but insertion/removal may be linear (although optimized when it happens at the front and back of the array). So it really depends on what you need.

Comment: @Clever: Fundamentally, if you need an ordered container, use an array. If you need an unordered container, use a set. Note that sets are also uniquing, unlike an array, so if you don't want that property then don't use a set after all.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is "intersect" :)

```
if ([a intersectsSet:b]) {
    ...
}
```